# ActiveStorage: Detach (instead of purge) attachment after owner record is destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

The Rails API documentation states [the following](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Macros.html#method-i-has_many_attached) about `has_many_attached` and `has_one_attched` methods:

> If the :dependent option isn't set, all the attachments will be purged (i.e. destroyed) whenever the record is destroyed.

Specifically, what value should I specify for this option?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Rails 5.2. The documentation is not great, but the source code helps to fill in the gaps. Here are a few lines from the relevant file (the code is identical for both `has_one_attached` and `has_many_attached`):

```
# /active_storage/attached/macros.rb

def has_one_attached(name, dependent: :purge_later)

  ...

  if dependent == :purge_later
    after_destroy_commit { public_send(name).purge_later }
  else
    before_destroy { public_send(name).detach }
  end
end
```

Per the method definition (again, this is identical for both `has_one_attached` and `has_many_attached`), `:dependent` will be set to `:purge_later` if it is not otherwise specified. So you get the following results when the underlying record is deleted:

`has_one_attached :photo`

Will result in the photo being purged.

`has_one_attached :photo, dependent: :purge_later`

Will result in the photo being purged.

`has_one_attached :photo, dependent: :detach`

Will result in the photo being detached, but the active storage blob being left intact.

**Note that anything other than `:purge_later` will result in attachments being detached rather than purged.** So perversely:

`has_one_attached :photo, dependent: :purge`

Will result in the photo being **detached, not purged**.

The code appears to have gone through significant refactoring in Rails 6, so this oddity may have been addressed.

UPDATE: This issue [has been submitted](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36423) in Rails 5.2 and there is a [pending PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36433).

Answer (score -1):

Adding `:nullify` might do the trick for you. See the doc: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options

Comment: The docs you refer to are for standard ActiveRecord associations, not ActiveStorage dependencies.